# Haskell monad for simulation

Tags: haskell

What is the best way to represent state updated by input?

I simulate physical system. It has state (coordinates, velocities). State is updated by simulation that takes some parameters (forces) from `stdin`. Result goes to `stdout` after each simulation cycle.

Program should stop after N cycles.

I've done it with `readIORef` and `writeIORef` but this is ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to do this would be brachiating along a lazy (possibly infinite) list instead of doing any explicit IO.

```
import Control.Monad.State

-- Prerequisites:

data SimState     -- coordinates & velocities.
data SimTVParams  -- what's read from input.   `instance Read`.

initialState :: SimState
simStep :: SimTVParams -> SimState -> SimState
simStateInfo :: SimState -> String

-- How to do the simulation:

main :: IO ()
main = interact $ 
          unlines . map simStateInfo
        . simulate initialState
        . map read . lines

simulate :: SimState -> [SimTVParams] -> [SimState]
simulate iState = (`evalState` iState) . mapM (state . step)
 where step params oldState = (newState, newState)
        where newState = simStep params oldState
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't quit after N step. But I can do this passing stdin through head -n N in sh.

Comment: Right. Halting on `eof` rather than a fixed number of steps is much more natural for such a kind of task.

Answer (score 2):

You an write this at a very high-level using `pipes`.  First, I will assume that you have already defined the following types, values, and functions:

```
data Status = Status deriving (Show)
data Param = Param deriving (Read)

initialState :: Status
initialState = undefined

update :: Status -> Param -> Status
update = undefined

numCycles :: Int
numCycles = undefined
```

Now here comes the pipes code:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

main = runEffect $
    P.readLn >-> P.take numCycles >-> P.scan update initialState id >-> P.print
```

You can read this as a data processing pipeline from left to right:

- `P.readLn` reads input parameters from standard input.  It will halt if you reach end of input
- `P.take numCycles` only allows up to `numCycles` parameters to pass through
- `P.scan` runs your simulation using the provided initial state and update function and then streams each intermediate state further downstream
- `P.print` prints out each intermediate state

To learn more about the `pipes` library, you can read the [official `pipes` tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.0.2/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html).